Armature Movement From SolidWorks to Blender
How can I export an assembly from SolidWorks using a STEP file to Blender, and create armatures for movement, considering that I’ve already exported the file and tried to create bones between the assembly and the armature in Pose Mode, but it doesn’t work? What is the best way please?
